# How to create a list of lists using itertools combination function?

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

i have a list with 1's and 0's. I want to know all possible combinations of them and store each combination in a list of lists.
Why are they stored as Tuples, and how to change that ?

```
import itertools

bitcode = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]

# print(len(bitcode))

listoflist = [[]]


combo_all = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(bitcode, 11)

for bitcode in combo_all:
    listoflist.append(bitcode)

# print(listoflist)
# print(len(listoflist))
# print(type(listoflist))
print(listoflist[-1])
print(type(listoflist[-1]))
```

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are they stored as Tuples?

Because that's how the `itertools` module is implemented. `itertools.product`, `itertools.combinations` and the like yield tuples.

> how to change that?

Convert the tuples to lists:

```
combo_all = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(bitcode, 11)
combo_all = map(list, combo_all)  # this doesn't iterate over `combo_all`
```

The code above doesn't loop over anything or store potentially immense amounts of data anywhere (unlike `list(combo_all)`). It may not be necessary to store *all* of the combinations in memory at once, so you may be better off iterating over each of them without storing all of them (in case you're searching for a particular combination or writing them line by line to a file).

If you *need* to have all of the combinations in memory, convert `combo_all` to a list:

```
combo_all = list(combo_all)
```